# How to auto scrolling of collectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, uicollectionview

When I drag section and move of `UICollectionView` using longPress Gesture then how to auto scroll `UICollectionView's` scrollview.

Note: in `UICollectionView` section 0 and 1 not scroll down, onward section only scrolling. 0 and 1 section set as sticky which is not scrolling when I move section.

Comment: You question bit confusing me now. If I understood correctly.You want the collectionViewCell moves when touches every time to centre,left or right is that what you want or you want the collection scroll when its load to the view...You need different approach to achieve this.let me know.personally I am using the above code in my project. I never had a issue with the code.let me know..

Comment: then you won't  get the answers.just make a simple test project that simulate your problem and upload that code.You have to give us something so we return as your favour... good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

```
 func handleLongGesture(gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) { //dragging Functionality handled here.
    let point = gesture.locationInView(self.collectionView)
    switch(gesture.state) {

        case UIGestureRecognizerState.Changed:
        let gesturePoint = gesture.locationInView(self.collectionView)
        guard let changeIndexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathForItemAtPoint(gesturePoint)
            where changeIndexPath.section > 1 else {
            break
        }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

UnTested Code:

Try this code inside your viewDidload or viewWillAppear.

```
   let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 10, inSection: 0) // 1
    self.collectionView.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.Left, animated: true)
```

Comment: i already implement this code but it's not working as i asking in question

Comment: using scrollToItemAtIndexPath also scroll the section 0 and section 1

Comment: sorry i can't share